# quickfix messege out of window

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

When i run the make cmd inside the vim using :Make it shows the quickfix windows where erros are shwon if their is. What my problem is as i saw, the error messeges are not crop or wraped inside the visible window instead to view or read the full msg i have to mvoe to right side of the window using L cmd. How can i view this error messages without moving right side instead of wraping it inside the window width? Here first screen shot represents the normal output of make cmd and the second screen shot shows same msg but after i moved at right side of the error msg.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vim: wrap long :make lines in message dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129813/vim-wrap-long-make-lines-in-message-dialog)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+quickfix+wrap

Comment: ok, looks like becaus i didn't used the correct key word to find its solution i got this problem. now problem is solved.